# Android: Integrating Video chat using Vidyo

Tags: android, jar, video-streaming, chat, videochat

I am using Vidyo android sdk for integrating video chat in my app.I have tested it with autogenerated token and it works fine. Vidyo provides a jar file to get accesstoken.How can i run this jar file in android studio to generate access token dynamically inside my app? I have tried this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "absolute path upto jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

but what would be the absolute path of jar when it is placed in android studio.I need to pass the parameters too while executing this jar and get the returned accessToken.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with the legacy Vidyo product or Vidyo.io?

If its Vidyo.io, then you should not be generating tokens within the app itself. You should make a call to your backend, where the token would be generated, and returned to your app.